# How can I remove this (unportable) nested function?

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers

I have a function that sorts a list of pointers to structures (implementation omitted):

```
void sort_by(struct thing **start, int size,
    int (*cmp_by)(struct thing *, struct thing *));
```

This function allows me to pass in a comparison function `cmp_by` that takes two structures and returns `1`, `0`, `-1` as appropriate.  Then there exists this (GCC-only!) function:

```
void reverse_by(struct thing **start, int size,
        int (*cmp_by)(struct thing *, struct thing *)) {

    int cmp_reverse(struct thing *a, struct thing *b) {
        return -cmp_by(a, b);
    }

    sort_by(start, size, cmp_reverse);
}
```

This function, takes the same arguments as `sort_by` but **reverses** the sort order by flipping the sign of the result of comparison.  GCC has this extension to allow nested functions.  How should `reverse_by` be written portably?  Even my attempts at getting this to work come nowhere near to compiling:

```
int (*reverse(int (*fn)(struct thing *, struct thing *)))(struct thing *, struct thing *) {
    return -fn;  /* OBVIOUSLY AND CONCEPTUALLY WRONG */
}
int (*reverse(int (*fn)(struct thing *a, struct thing *b)))(struct thing *x, struct thing *y) {
    return -fn(a, b);  /* WRONG RETURN TYPE WRONG WRONG */
}
int (*reverse(int (*fn)(struct thing *a, struct thing *b)))(struct thing *x, struct thing *y) {
    return -fn(x, y);  /* YOU HAVE NO IDEA WHAT YOU'RE DOING STOP GUESSING */
}
```

Short of adding a lot of extra structure parts or rewriting swaths of code calling `reverse_by` (or copy-pasting `sort_by` code into it), how can this be rewritten to eliminate the nested function?  It would be good to avoid copy/paste as a solution because this code base involves this nested-function-pattern elsewhere.

Comment: To remove this (unportable) nested function move the definition of `cmp_reverse()` outside `reverse_by()`.  Maybe tag it `static`?

Comment: Does it need to be re-entrant? Given that you can't pass in an extra parameter to your comparison function, you could have a static variable that you stash the comparison function in, and then wrap that static function pointer with a static `cmp_reverse`. Totally not re-entrant, though.

Comment: Note that with a global you can even make it re-entrant, just not thread safe. Thread safe would require either a lock or a thread-local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-entrant but not thread-safe solution:

```
typedef int (*cmp_func)(struct thing *, struct thing *);

static cmp_func reverse_cmp_by_impl;

static int cmp_reverse(struct thing *a, struct thing *b) {
    int ret;
    cmp_func impl = reverse_cmp_by_impl;
    ret = -impl(a, b);
    reverse_cmp_by_impl = impl; // For re-entrancy
    return ret;
}

void reverse_by(struct thing **start, int size, cmp_func cmp_by) {
    reverse_cmp_by_impl = cmp_by;
    sort_by(start, size, cmp_reverse);
}
```

Note that this is assuming a sane implementation of `sort_by`. i.e. one that doesn't call `reverse_by` in any way except potentially through the comparison function.